# how to @importFrom data.table within r package function

Tags: r

I have a function in a package I am developing. I don't think the input data is relevant so I haven't posted it. I am trying to only import specific functions from packages into this function as per recommendations and this mostly works fine apart from for data.table.

```
#' @importFrom data.table 'setDT' 'rowid' '.SD'
 #' @keywords Sankey
 #' @export
    SurveySankey <- function(dfw, y,PatientID) {
      # Create the Sankey diagrams
      Sankey <-
        dcast(data.table::setDT(dfw)[, .SD, PatientID], 
              PatientID ~ rowid(PatientID),
              value.var = y)
    }
```

If I do as above I get the error:

```
1. Error: SurveySankey (@test.R#400) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
object '.SD' not found
```

but if instead of the `@importfrom` statement I use

```
#' @import data.table
```

it runs fine. I don't want to use the latter as some of the function names clash with other packages. How can I import `.SD` - perhaps this isn't the importable function?

Comment: I didn't try it but I found a new tag "@rawNamespace" that could help (https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/10/29/roxygen2-5-0-0/). Perhaps something like `@rawNamespace "importFrom(data.table, .SD, .N, .I, .GRP, .BY, .EACHI)"` works (see also https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports)

Comment: Did you accidentally misspell the `@importFrom` tag in your code (or only here at SO)? -> capital F !

Comment: A reproducible data set for the param "dfw" would be helpful, I have problems to provoke the exact same error message... Thx :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.SD` is not a function at all.

[In the source code of the package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R) you can see, that `.SD` is only exported to prevent NOTEs:

```
.SD = .N = .I = .GRP = .BY = .EACHI = NULL
# These are exported to prevent NOTEs from R CMD check, and checkUsage via compiler.
# But also exporting them makes it clear (to users and other packages) that data.table uses these as symbols.
# And NULL makes it clear (to the R's mask check on loading) that they're variables not functions.
# utils::globalVariables(c(".SD",".N")) was tried as well, but exporting seems better.
# So even though .BY doesn't appear in this file, it should still be NULL here and exported because it's
# defined in SDenv and can be used by users.
```

You can try to import `'special-symbols'` from `data.table`:

```
#' @importFrom data.table "special-symbols"
```

ALternatively, you could just add this line `.SD = .N = .I = .GRP = .BY = .EACHI = NULL` to your package.

Comment: @clemens Have you found a documentation of "special-symbols" or how did you find this out?

Comment: I added .SD to the utils::globalVariables in the end as it was the simplest. I couldnt get @importFrom data.table "special-symbols" to work.